# How can i plot a 3D surface from excel data

Tags: matlab, dataset, matlab-figure

I have a dataset from an excel file. The first row is the temperatures and The first column the wavelengths.

I have about 60 columns with the intensities and I want to plot a surface. I'm not finding a solution to the error

> "Error using surf (line 57)
>
> Z must be a matrix, not a scalar or vector."*

```
num =xlsread('Amostra_1.xlsx');
x=num(1,:); y=num(2,1); 
for n = 2:51
z=num(2,n);
x = linspace(40,450,length(z));
y = linspace(200,800,length(z));
end
```

How can I convert this `z` columns into a matrix

Thanks

Comment: You should try [`meshgrid`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html) and/or [`griddata`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/griddata.html).